# Intellij IDEA Inspection background color not appearing for certain warnings

Tags: intellij-idea

Currently experiencing an issue where the background color I have set for `warning`s only shows up on certain warnings.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTFWM.png)

The inspections/warnings for line 19 show the background color correctly in addition to the orange line on the right gutter.

However, the inspection for Unused parameter *only* displays in the right gutter, but does not highlight.  This doesn't seem to make sense as both are warnings and don't seem to be controlled by separate styles in `Color & Fonts > General > Errors and Warnings`.

Any ideas?  I tried loading my PyCharm profile (where this works as expected) but to no avail.

Version: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 Build #IU-145.1617, built on June 3, 2016 JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b198 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IJ 14 (at least) `Unused symbols` is controlled by a separate style under `Color & Fonts > General`:

[image: Unused symbol]

Comment: Totally worked, thanks a ton that was going to drive me crazy.

Comment: @diplosaurus you're welcome, and if I saved you some time, you can spend it quenching that crazyness, with a beer for example